# Is event handler code "persistent" after disabling JS?

Tags: validation, document-ready, javascript

I noticed something interesting while testing the client side validation on a website that used jquery document.ready event.

If I loaded the login page with js disabled its `noscript` tag redirects the user to a different page informing that the js support wasn't enabled on the browser.

If I loaded the login page with js enabled, and then proceed to disable it, the code attached on its document.ready event was still running and validated perfectly the empty inputs in its login and password fields.

Since I didn't see the page requesting to the server to perform such validation I wonder if its correct to assume that the fact that js was initially enabled was enough for the document.ready to run and attach the code permanently no matter how I toggle the js support afterwards? or Maybe I missed something?.

Thanks for the insight you all can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Disable javascript" would actually be closer to reality if called "Disable js from now on". Everything that was executed before disabling, well, was executed. Everything that would have happened after the disabling (such as timeouts, intervals, etc), is no longer executed.

Comment: So since document.ready event was triggered on page load and finished/done, the code attached to it will run no matter if I disable the js support afterwards? (with no page reloading of course).

Comment: This seems to be a logic reason for the webpage to behave as it did, if you can please confirm my comment to mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Browsers still run JS on *currently opened pages* even after you disable JS in your settings. Any new pages loaded while JS is disabled will have their scripts disabled.

It's like the browser only checks that setting only on page load:

```
Load page -> is scipts on? -> yes -> run        //changing it anywhere after
                           -> no  -> do not run //does not affect it's status
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, actually I thought that but i have tried testing a form with an alert attached to the onclick event of a link and it doesn't shows anymore right after I toggle the js support on the page with no page reload.